# An iterative program for appending lists in scheme

Tags: linked-list, scheme, sicp

I am reading Section 2.2 in SICP where the book introduced the procedure for appending two lists. I am trying to implement the append using iteration.

This is my code:

```
(define (append list1 list2)
  (define (append-iter item1 reversed-item1 result)
    (if (null? item1)
      (if (null? reversed-item1)
        result
        (append-iter item1 
                     (cdr reversed-item1) 
                     (cons (car reverse) result)))
      (append-iter (cdr item1) 
                   (cons (car item1) reversed-item1) 
                   result)))
  (append-iter list1 '() list2))
```

Though it works, but noting the number of the iterations is double the length of `list1`. Is there a solution whose number of the iterations equals to the length of `list1`. (without using any fold function)?

Answer (score 1):

Basically how your procedure works is like this:

```
(define (append l1 l2)
  (define (reverse-append rev app)
    (if (null? rev)
        app
        (reverse-append (cdr rev) 
                        (cons (car rev) app))))
  (reverse-append (reverse l1) l2))
```

It's O(N) but it wastes some memory since `(reverse l1)` space is just used for iteration. If you really need to fix that you need to use mutation:

```
(define (append-iter . rest)
  (let ((result (list 1)))
    (let loop ((p result) (lst '()) (rest rest))
      (cond
        ((not (null? lst))
         (set-cdr! p (list (car lst)))
         (loop (cdr p) (cdr lst) rest))
        ((null? rest) (cdr result))
        ((null? (cdr rest))
         (set-cdr! p (car rest))
         (cdr result))
        (else (loop p (car rest) (cdr rest)))))))
```